# Colouring a specific point in a scatterplot in R

Tags: r

I'm somewhat new to R and ggplot2. I've been trying to create a scatterplot graph that has one specific point coloured. For example, here is my basic data frame

```
manager     Confirmed Overturned  keeping  Stands  total
A.J. Hinch     11         24         0       14     49
Angel Hernandez 0          1         0        0      1
Bill Miller     3          1         0        4      8
Bob Melvin      6         16         0        6      28
Brad Ausmus     3         11         0       13      27
```

With this I can create a simple scatterplot using this code,

```
p <- ggplot(data = Outcome, aes(x = Overturned, y = total))
p + geom_point()
```

I know how to add general colour, and add a colour scale, but I don't know how to colour just one point. For example, let's say I wanted to colour A.J. Hinch blue, and make every other point a different colour (probably grey or black), how would I do that?

Here is a link to the graph I want to create in Tableau. 
https://public.tableau.com/profile/julien1554#!/vizhome/ManagerChallenges2014-2015/Sheet1

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It seems like you want to create a column including two levels. One for `A.J. Hinch` and the other for the rest. You can use the column to specify colors.

Comment: `ggplot(df, aes(x = Overturned, y = total, colour = manager == 'A.J. Hinch')) + geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) + scale_color_manual(values = c('gray', 'blue'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would just add another scatter plot layer to your plot. Here is the code that I used. Hope it helps!

```
> df = as.data.frame(cbind(Overturned = c(24,1,1,16,11), total = c(49,1,8,28,27)))
> library(ggplot2)
> p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Overturned, y = total)) # creates the graph
> p + geom_point(data = df, color = "gray") + # creates main scatter plot with gray points
   geom_point(data = df[1,], color = "blue") # colors A.J. Hinch's point blue
```

Here is the resulting graph:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Note that I'm just using the last name because when I read your data from the clipboard it thought the first names were row labels.

```
Outcome$color_me <- ifelse(Outcome$manager == "Hinch", "color_me", "normal")
textdf           <- Outcome[Outcome$manager == "Hinch", ]
mycolors         <- c("color_me" = "blue", "normal" = "grey50")

ggplot(data = Outcome, aes(x = Overturned, y = total)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(colour = color_me))
```

[image]

or with the manually defined color:

```
ggplot(data = Outcome, aes(x = Overturned, y = total)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(colour = color_me)) +
  scale_color_manual("Status", values = mycolors)
```

[image]